# Pandas extract part of string form a column in a dataframe and store it in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, extract

I have the below code to create a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = {'Connection':['Home 10Mbps','Broadband 5 Mbps','128 Kbps Internet','Discounted 512Kbps 2 years contract']}
df = pd.DataFrame (df)
df
```

I need a way to extract only the bandwidth from column "Connection" and store the result in new column named for example "Bandwidth" to look something like this:

Bandwidth

10 Mbps

5 Mbps

128 Kbps

512 Kbps

Comment: Your data does not follow a pattern, so it is not possible or at least unnecessarily hard to parse it. Since you already have the data, why don't you put it into a separate column when you initialize the dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in fact this is part of a 300 K record dataset and I need to do this in the process of cleansing and organizing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to fill the list with all possible formats

```
lst = ['10Mbps', '10 Mbps', '5 Mbps', '128 Kbps', '512Kbps', '512 Kbps']
for i in lst:
   df.loc[df['Connection'].str.contains(i), 'bandwidth'] = i

lst1 = []
for j in df.bandwidth:
  if " " not in j:
    lst1.append((re.sub("[A-Za-z]+", lambda ele: " " + ele[0] + " ", j)[:-1]))
  else:
    lst1.append(j)

df['bandwidth']=lst1

# output
Connection                 bandwidth
Home 10Mbps                 10 Mbps
Broadband 5 Mbps            5 Mbps
128 Kbps Internet           128 Kbps
Discounted 512Kbps 2 years contract 512 Kbps
```

Comment: Thank you, this should do it, this data is part of a 300 K record that I am working on, still I will need to resolve how to unify the values; with a space or without a space between the number and the bandwidth unit, do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: I edited the response if that's what you meant

Comment: Perfect, Thanks

Comment: You're welcome please accept the answer if everything is okay.